# Problema com jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery

Estou utilizando o recurso `remote` para verificar se existe um cadastro em meu banco de dados com o mesmo cpf. 
Mais preciso que esse campo não seja obrigatório seja opcional.

Então tentei colocar `required: false` mais não dá certo existe essa possibilidade ou se tratando de uma consulta ele só será obrigatório.

```
cpf: {
cpf: true,                          
remote: {
    url: "/clientes/consulta_cliente",
    type: "post",
    data: {cpf: function(){ return $("input[name='cpf']").val();}}
}}
```

código pra fazer a validade `cpf:true`

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cpf", function(value, element) {
value = value.replace('.','');
value = value.replace('.','');
cpf = value.replace('-','');
while(cpf.length < 11) cpf = "0"+ cpf;
var expReg = /^0+$|^1+$|^2+$|^3+$|^4+$|^5+$|^6+$|^7+$|^8+$|^9+$/;
var a = [];
var b = new Number;
var c = 11;
for (i=0; i<11; i++){
    a[i] = cpf.charAt(i);
    if (i < 9) b += (a[i] * --c);
}
if ((x = b % 11) < 2) { a[9] = 0 } else { a[9] = 11-x }
b = 0;
c = 11;
for (y=0; y<10; y++) b += (a[y] * c--);
if ((x = b % 11) < 2) { a[10] = 0; } else { a[10] = 11-x; }
if ((cpf.charAt(9) != a[9]) || (cpf.charAt(10) != a[10]) || cpf.match(expReg)) return false;
return true;
}, "Informe um CPF válido.");
```

Comment: Qual é a mensagem que te aparece ao colocares não colocares CPF no Formulário? Que queres dizer com `cpf: true`?

Comment: jorge eu tirei isso e parece que der certo, não tinha prestado atenção nisso, peguei um exemplo na net mais parece que deu

Comment: Qualquer coisa manda ai :)

Comment: precisa sim, o cpf é um função que adicionei no scrip para validar o cpf.

Comment: Vê a minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu utilizo essa função, ela possui 3 metodos, um para validar só CPF outro so para CNPJ e outro chamado documento que valida os dois de acordo com a quantidade de caracteres no campo. Ele valida sem precisar fazer dependências e se o campo tiver vazio ele não da pau no campo.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("documento", function(value, element) {

    // remove pontuações
    value = value.replace('.', '');
    value = value.replace('.', '');
    value = value.replace('-', '');
    value = value.replace('/', '');

    if (value.length <= 11) {
        if (jQuery.validator.methods.cpf.call(this, value, element)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.settings.messages.documento = "Informe um CPF valido.";
        }

    }
    else if (value.length <= 14) {
        if (jQuery.validator.methods.cnpj.call(this, value, element)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.settings.messages.documento = "Informe um CNPJ valido.";
        }

    }

    return false;

}, "Informe um documento valido.");





// validação do CPF
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cpf", function(value, element) {
    value = jQuery.trim(value);

    value = value.replace('.', '');
    value = value.replace('.', '');
    cpf = value.replace('-', '');
    while (cpf.length < 11)
        cpf = "0" + cpf;
    var expReg = /^0+$|^1+$|^2+$|^3+$|^4+$|^5+$|^6+$|^7+$|^8+$|^9+$/;
    var a = [];
    var b = 0;
    var c = 11;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        a[i] = cpf.charAt(i);
        if (i < 9)
            b += (a[i] * --c);
    }
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) {
        a[9] = 0;
    } else {
        a[9] = 11 - x;
    }
    b = 0;
    c = 11;
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        b += (a[y] * c--);
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) {
        a[10] = 0;
    } else {
        a[10] = 11 - x;
    }

    var retorno = true;
    if ((cpf.charAt(9) != a[9]) || (cpf.charAt(10) != a[10]) || cpf.match(expReg))
        retorno = false;

    return this.optional(element) || retorno;

}, "Informe um CPF válido.");


// validação do CNPJ
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cnpj", function(cnpj, element) {
    cnpj = jQuery.trim(cnpj);// retira espaços em branco
    // DEIXA APENAS OS NÚMEROS
    cnpj = cnpj.replace('/', '');
    cnpj = cnpj.replace('.', '');
    cnpj = cnpj.replace('.', '');
    cnpj = cnpj.replace('-', '');

    var numeros, digitos, soma, i, resultado, pos, tamanho, digitos_iguais;
    digitos_iguais = 1;

    if (cnpj.length < 14 && cnpj.length < 15) {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cnpj.length - 1; i++) {
        if (cnpj.charAt(i) != cnpj.charAt(i + 1)) {
            digitos_iguais = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!digitos_iguais) {
        tamanho = cnpj.length - 2;
        numeros = cnpj.substring(0, tamanho);
        digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
        soma = 0;
        pos = tamanho - 7;

        for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
            soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
            if (pos < 2) {
                pos = 9;
            }
        }
        resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
        if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0)) {
            return false;
        }
        tamanho = tamanho + 1;
        numeros = cnpj.substring(0, tamanho);
        soma = 0;
        pos = tamanho - 7;
        for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
            soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
            if (pos < 2) {
                pos = 9;
            }
        }
        resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
        if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, "Informe um CNPJ valido."); // Mensagem padrão
```

Comment: valeu Euler mais eu já tinha testado com essa função eu acho que problema é devido a função remoto acho que as duas juntos sem esse macete que o jorge me passou não funciona, porque se tirar a função remote ele funciona certinho

Answer (score 1):

Quando uma verificação depende de uma entrada pelo utilizadores deves utilizar o `depends`, que retorna *true* ou *false* para o `cpf` segundo uma condição, neste caso o campo estar vazio ou não:

```
cpf: {
    cpf: {
        depends: function () {
            return $("input[name='cpf']").val()!='';
        }
    },                          
    remote: {
        url: "/clientes/consulta_cliente",
       type: "post",
       data: {cpf: function(){ return $("input[name='cpf']").val();}}
   }
}
```

Assim garantes que só no caso do valor do CPF ser diferente de vazio é que faz a verificação.

Como tens no teu código ele vai sempre verificar o cpf independentemente de existir ou não.

Comment: onde devo colocar? poque estou colocando antes cpf:true

Comment: Em vez de `cpf:true`.

Comment: O `depends` vai se encarregar de dizer se é `cpf:true` ou `cpf:false` consoante tenhas ou não o cpf preenchido.

Comment: amigo intendi a sua lógica mais infelizmente não sei onde devo colcoar.

Comment: Vê a minha edição.

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou... Deus te abençoe...